# Accessing scoped enumerators via class member access operator

Tags: c++, enums, clang, scoped-enums

Sample unit:

```cpp
struct Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
{
    enum class Frob
    {
        Foo, Bar, Baz, Qux
    };

    Frob frob;
};

Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious maker();

void f()
{
    auto g = maker();

    // Allowed?
    if ( g.frob == g.Frob::Baz ) {}
}
```

This code is accepted by gcc 9.x and 10.x, but rejected by clang 10.x and 11.x ([godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hvKW8x)) with an error like:

```
<source>:17:28: error: 'Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious::Frob::Baz' is not a member of class 'Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'
```

**My question is:** is this code correct (i.e. is it just a clang bug?)

---

*Background*: I'd like to test `g.frob == Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious::Frob::Baz` but without having to repeat the classname.  And in a more general situation where we obtained the object by `auto`, the classname might not immediately be obvious, or could be difficult due to templates.

I came up with the workaround of `decltype(g)::Frob::Baz` which seems to work in both compilers for the above code -- although if `g` were a reference, this is again accepted by gcc and rejected by clang.

Comment: In MSVC, it compiles and runs, though Intellisense complains: `Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious::Frob::Baz is not a class member`.

Comment: @Casey I get the same in my gcc IDE -- which is because the IDE uses clang for intellisense

Comment: Yeah, I tend to ignore intellisense and only listen to the compiler. There were cases where MSVC's compiler team implemented newer features but the intellisense team didn't so it complained, but your code still worked.

Comment: In any case, `decltype` seems an appropriate workaround for not having to type a long typename. I use it in other contexts a lot because lazy.

Comment: In my real code `g` is actually a reference so the decltype workaround doesn't help

Comment: Can you put an example of that in your question?

Comment: I decided to stick to 1 question per question ... will post a follow-up depending on how this one is answered.  (But just go `auto& h = g;` and try to do it on `h`)

Comment: `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(h)>::Frob::Baz` works

Comment: @Casey The cure is nearly worse than the problem

Comment: Although, if your class name is actually that long, you have some design issues you should look in to. :P